Find location $x$ with $3$ given points, $1$ given angle at points and two angles at point $x$
I'm working on a hobby project with kids. We're building a small rover that we can send locations to and have it drive.
I want to set up three locations - $p_1$, $p_2$, $p_3$ These points are in known locations measured out with a tape measure. We also know angle $p_1-p_2-p_3$.
We are looking to solve $xy$ for the rover.
Now, we want to build a little robot to drive around. This robot will have a custom device, that spins, on the top of it. We have a $24$bit encoder attached to this device, so we can get the angle as this device spins.
Now, we attach a laser to this spinning device, along with a receiver. So, this is going to spin, then when the laser is perfectly in line with $p_1$, we get a reading - same for $p_2$ and $p_3$.
We won't know the distance; however we can get the angle from the encoder.
We know the location of $p_1$, $p_2$, and $p_3$ and we know the angle between $p_1$, $p_2$, and $p_3$.
How do we get the $xy$ of the rover (i.e. $P_X$)? I remember doing this back in school, many years ago...but for the life of me, I can't seem to get exactly what I am looking for...
Known information:

distance $p_1-p_2 = 240$
distance $p_2-p_3 = 120$
angle $p_1,p_2,p_3 = 101.387259^\circ$

Rover known information:

$P_X$ is rover center point
$p_1-p_x-p_2 = 68.848678^\circ$
$p_2-p_x-p_3 = 35.912409^\circ$

Here is a picture to help explain.

I tried searching Google for triangulation, intersection, resection, and several other formula terms... all to no avail for my particular question.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Given that you know angle p1-px-p2, the locus of possible points are 2 circular arcs (with endpoints of p1-p2). Likewise for p2-px-p3. You can hope that these 2 loci have a unique intersection, but I don't think that is guaranteed.

i maybe wrong but wouldnt i need to know the distance of radius to use circular arcs

Here's another route (again, because the Stack Overflow thread was prematurely closed).
Let the angle at P1 be theta. Then, by the sine rule for the bottom triangle:
dist(P2,PX) = sin(theta) * dist(P2,P1) / sin(A2)       - call this a.sin(theta)

whilst for the top triangle, with A=A1+A2+A3,
dist(P2,PX) = sin(360-theta-A) * dist(P2,P3) / sin(A3)       - call this -b.sin(theta+A), since sin(360-x)=-sin(x)

Equating the two expressions and expanding:
a.sin(theta) = -b[sin(theta)cos(A)+cos(theta)sin(A)]

Rearranging:
(a+b.cos(A)).sin(theta) = -b.sin(A).cos(theta)

whence
tan(theta) = -b.sin(A)/(a+b.cos(A))

Once you have theta and dist(P2,PX) then you can simply rotate vector P2.P1 about P2 by angle 180-A2-theta and rescale to the correct length to get the coordinates of PX.
Here's the answer in Python that I was trying to compose on Stack Overflow when somebody shut down the thread.
from math import *

radToDeg = 180 / pi
degToRad = pi / 180

def rotate( x, y, theta ):
    return x * cos( theta ) - y * sin( theta ), x * sin( theta ) + y * cos( theta )

def dist( x1, y1, x2, y2 ):
    return sqrt( ( x2 - x1 ) ** 2 + ( y2 - y1 ) ** 2 )

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------

A1, A2, A3 = 101.387259 * degToRad, 68.848678 * degToRad, 35.912409 * degToRad
X1, Y1 = -70.715748, -119.864536
X2, Y2 = -59.315235,  119.864536
d21 = dist( X1, Y1, X2, Y2 )
d23 = 120
dx, dy = rotate( X1 - X2, Y1 - Y2, A1 )
X3, Y3 = X2 + ( d23 / d21 ) * dx, Y2 + ( d23 / d21 ) * dy

a = d21 / sin( A2 )
b = d23 / sin( A3 )
A = A1 + A2 + A3

theta = atan2( -b * sin( A ), a + b * cos( A ) )
d2x = a * sin( theta )
dx, dy = rotate( X1 - X2, Y1 - Y2, pi - theta - A2 )
X, Y = X2 + ( d2x / d21 ) * dx, Y2 + ( d2x / d21 ) * dy

print( "Answer: X, Y = ", X, Y )

Answer: X, Y =  109.0836,  13.3560

thanks lastchance this works perfectly for us we are currently tweeking to fit ardunio i will post results when finished

The original question from StackOverflow was closed so I'll post the update here, I appologize in advance for my writing:
answer part 1
answer part 2.
I didn't solve completely the problem, I simply explained the first steps.
From there, you'll have to solve the equation for A6, the only unknown.
Afterwards, calculate the edge P2-PX using A6 and the Law of sines. You'll also need the other two edges (PX-P1 and PX-P3) that you'll be able to calculate using your favorite formula (Law of sines or cosines).
Once you have all the distances, use the distance formula to setup 3 equations (from PX to each known point) and solve the system to find the X and Y coordinates of PX.
